# php application hooking event hooking using separate process

Tags: php, model-view-controller, hook

What is the accepted way of having the php app do a bunch of processing in the background?

I know there's a way to `session_commit` and the user has the page rendered and the process can continue other actions.

I'd like to integrate a hook with models, but this approach would require to branch into a separate process. Are there any examples of this working somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean a queue system like pheanstalk? What kind of jobs you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'm not certain, but it looks like that may be the better term for it.

Comment: There are couple of libraries that will help you run background processes like beanstalkd (pheanstalk is the php lib for it) or Laravel (if you are able to use it) has a queue system built into it. [Good read about them](http://queues.io/) I think is a good start.